# Opening xcode 3.2 VST project in xcode 4

Tags: xcode4, vst

I recently started a project using Xcode 3.2 and the vstsdk 2.4 and then I purchased Xcode 4.  When I open the project within Xcode 4 I get the "missing base SDK" error which I can fix by changing that to either Mac OS X 10.5 or 10.6.  After this though my .vst file is still red in the file tree.  I have also tried to delete the file and re-add it but when I do it adds it as a folder instead of a .vst file.  Without this I cannot build the project as the target is missing.

Any ideas?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file "yourplugin.vst" (or whatever it's named) in the Xcode group is actually the product's output target, so you shouldn't delete it. If it's red, that simply means that you haven't built the target yet.

If you are using source control, I would advise reverting back to the version before you deleted the .vst file and trying to build from that point. If you're not (and why aren't you?! ;) ), then you can try re-creating the target manually.

I have also written a tutorial on how to make a [VST plugin in Xcode](http://www.teragonaudio.com/2010/06/making-vst-plugin-from-scratch-with.html) which you might find useful. I will be updating this for Xcode 4 soon, so if you run into any problems, post a comment there.

Comment: Thanks, I have got a copy saved where I have not deleted the .vst so I have reverted back to that copy but when I select the .vst but when I select it I cannot press build.  I can continue to work in Xcode 3.2 but Xcode 4 is so much better.  I also cannot create a new target as it won't let me select the a .vst file and the closest I can get is "bundle".

Comment: A VST is essentially a bundle with a custom extension. If you need to re-create the target, then just use the "bundle" type and set the extension to "vst" in the target properties.

Comment: Great thanks got it working again.  I added a new target and then built it and it also built the old .vst target so I just deleted the new one and it and it worked. After all that though I get over 100 errors in the vstGUI and vstControls files which are all written by Steinberg.  Think I need to update the vstsdk.  Cheers!